# Unity CG Texture Layering using Passes

Tags: unity-game-engine

This is what I’m trying to accomplish

1. Texture geometry with primary shader
2. Layer a second texture over the first one by a projected amount following the normal.

Here is my current shader code:

```
Shader "Custom/FurShader" 
{

Properties 

{

    _MainTex( "Main Texture", 2D ) = "white" {} 

    _MaxHairLength( "Max Hair Length", Float ) = 0.5

    _NoOfPasses( "Number of Passes", Float ) = 2.0

}



CGINCLUDE

//includes

#include "UnityCG.cginc"    



//structures

struct vertexInput

{

    float4 vertex : POSITION;

    float4 normal : NORMAL;

    float4 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;

};



struct fragmentInput 

{

    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;

    half2 uv : TEXCOORD0;           

};



//uniforms

uniform float _MaxHairLength;                       

uniform sampler2D _MainTex;

uniform float4 _MainTex_ST;



uniform sampler2D _SecondTex;

uniform float4 _SecondTex_ST;



uniform float _NoOfPasses;



//function

inline fragmentInput LevelFragmentShader( vertexInput i, int level )

{

    fragmentInput o;



    float movementDist = ( _MaxHairLength / _NoOfPasses ) * level;      



    float4 pos = ( i.vertex + ( i.normal * movementDist ) );             



    o.pos = mul( UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, pos );       

    o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX( i.texcoord, _SecondTex );



    return o;

}



half4 frag( fragmentInput i ) : COLOR

{

    return tex2D( _SecondTex, i.uv );

}



ENDCG



SubShader {

    Tags { "Queue" = "Transparent"}

    Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha



    Pass

    {   

        CGPROGRAM

        // Upgrade NOTE: excluded shader from OpenGL ES 2.0 because it does not contain a surface program or both vertex and fragment programs.

        #pragma exclude_renderers gles

        #pragma vertex vert 

        #pragma fragment frag_unique                    



        fragmentInput vert( vertexInput i )

        {

            fragmentInput o;



            o.pos = mul( UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, i.vertex );

            o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX( i.texcoord, _MainTex );               



            return o;

        }



        half4 frag_unique( fragmentInput i ) : COLOR

        {

            return tex2D( _MainTex, i.uv );

        }





        ENDCG

    }

    Pass

    {   

        CGPROGRAM

        // Upgrade NOTE: excluded shader from OpenGL ES 2.0 because it does not contain a surface program or both vertex and fragment programs.

        #pragma exclude_renderers gles

        #pragma vertex vert

        #pragma fragment frag                   



        fragmentInput vert( vertexInput i )

        {

            fragmentInput o = LevelFragmentShader( i, 1 );              



            return o;

        }





        ENDCG

    }



} 

FallBack "Diffuse"

}
```

But as you can see the result second texture is not projecting perpendicularly edge to edge. Any suggestions would be great, I'm sure my maths is correct vertxPos + ( Normal * projectionDistance). Could it be something to do with how I'm using unitys ModelViewProjection Matrix?

Image showing result
http://i1265.photobucket.com/albums/jj508/maxfire1/Capture_zpsc8db2b1f.png

Comment: What is the intended result of your layering?  Are you trying to achieve some form of texture splatting?

Comment: Thanks for your interest Jerdak. Eventually it will become a fur shader using shell texturing, each level will be a pass in the shader. I came up with this predicted implementation as unity does not allow you to manage the drawing call for each object via a script, not that I can find or any one on their forum can tell me anyway.

Comment: Ok after trying the same shared on a flat plane it works perfectly fine, I'm guessing unity does something to the normal of its cube  that I'm not aware of.